# how to highlight a textfield textfield named education by replacing the alertbox in js

Tags: javascript

Below is a code which alerts when the textfield is empty. I want to highlight the textfield named education by replacing the alertbox.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#update').click(function() {
        if (!$.trim($('#education').val())) {
            alert("Please select education");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#update').blur(function() {
        if ($('#education').val() == "" || $('#education').val()==null) {
            $("input").focus(function(){
             $("#education").css("border-style", "solid").css(" border-color","#ff0000");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $('#update').click(function() {
       if (!$.trim($('#education').val())) {
           //alert("Please select education");
           $('#education').focus();
       }
   });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/whollands/sgk0v9yf/

Answer (score 0):

you could try something along the lines of

```
  $("input[name='education']").select();
```

this will place the cursor in the text field. 
you could also add a class with something like

```
  $("input[name='education']").select().addClass("warning");
```

and style .warning to be bolder to highlight where the problem is